# Python: sentence splitting produces a whitespace

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have some sentences like:

```
The window is over there. The lamp is on. The fire is burning.
```

When I split it using split('.') and then join it with newlines, it loses the "."

Then I tried regex like `(?<=\.)\s` but it produces a space before the first letter of the second and third letters:

```
The window is over there.
 The lamp is on.
 The fire is burning.
```

I don't want that extra space. I want:

```
The window is over there.
The lamp is on.
The fire is burning.
```

Thanks

Comment: Your regex solution works fine for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
".\n".join(i.strip() for i in a.split("."))
```

Comment: Your final sentence has no `.`

Comment: Yes you are right. Well, assuming that every sentence is . terminated,  we can always add a "." at the end of the expression :). Otherwise, my solution does not cover this case..

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> test = "The window is over there. The lamp is on. The fire is burning."
>>> print test.replace(". ",".\n")
The window is over there.
The lamp is on.
The fire is burning.
```

Comment: Sure, I'll run with that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously not dealing with special cases (i.e. no space after a period), why not just do:

```
>>> s = 'The window is over there. The lamp is on. The fire is burning.'
>>> print s.replace('. ', '.\n')
The window is over there.
The lamp is on.
The fire is burning.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of dealing with splitting your input: stripping after splitting, using a regular expression to split or using a simple search .

The first option is perhaps the most intuitive: you split the string on a dot like you already do, and then strip the resulting strings to remove any whitespace and restore the trailing dot. In Python:

```
sentences = input.split('.')
sentences = [s.strip() + '.' for s in sentences if s]
print sentences.join('\n')
```

A second and simpler approach is to simple replace '. ' with '.\n':

```
print input.replace('. ', '.\n')
```

This will work with your input, but will fail if someone uses two spaces to separate sentences (which some people prefer).

The final and most flexible approach is to use a regular expression to split on the combination of a dot and whitespace:

```
import re
sentences = re.split('(?<=\.)\s*', input)
print sentences.join('\n')
```

Notice the important difference with your regular expression: I used \s* to consume all possible whitespace. This matters in cases where there are two or more spaces, or none at all.