# How to split python strings with multiple separators?

Tags: python, string, split, separator

I've string which includes some irrelevant characters 
for example :

`"t1, t2, t3"`

If I'm splitting it by `split(",")` method I'm getting a list where second and third items include also the white space.

How can I split required string with multiply separator ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: sentence splitting produces a whitespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307949/python-sentence-splitting-produces-a-whitespace)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need whitespace you could use :

```
"t1, t2, t3,t4".replace(" ", "").split(",")
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  It seems most people are recommending regular expressions, but I'm using this on an embedded system and each new library I have to pull in complicates it further.  Sometimes simpler *is* better.

Answer (score 6):

Either split them by `", "` (note the space) or `strip` the words after that:

```
[e.strip() for e in "t1, t2, t3,t4".split(",")]
>>> ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4']
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are arbitrary spaces after the commas, just strip the whitespace using a list comprehension:

```
[t.strip() for t in inputstring.split(',')]
```

or use a regular expression split (somewhat overkill in this situation):

```
import re

re.split(r',\s*', inputstring)
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> inputstring = 't1, t2, t3,t4,   t5'
>>> [t.strip() for t in inputstring.split(',')]
['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5']
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r',\s*', inputstring)
['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5']
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the obvious:

```
>>> "t1, t2, t3".split(', ')
['t1', 't2', 't3']
```

Comment: It's not so simple, what if I'll have 3 types of separators ?

Comment: @user301639: Then you should have said that in your question.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use strip().

```
s = "t1, t2, t3"
s = [x.strip() for x in s.split(",")]
print s
```